# Fill a RoundedRectangle with custom color

Tags: watchkit, swiftui

```
 RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous)
    .foregroundColor(Color.init(red: 255, green: 245, blue: 158))
```

My rounded rectangle is all white. Why can't I initiate a custom color? Whereas Color.red works perfectly fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Color.init(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat)
```

takes a 3 `CGFloat`s with values between 0 and 1

What you need is…

```
Color(red: 255/255, green: 245/255, blue: 158/255)
```

Note that the `.init` isn't required in Swift

Answer (score 3):

You can write an extension to take `Int`s as parameters to `Color` initializer. It will allow you to use `Color(red: 255, green: 245, blue: 158)`:

```
extension Color {

    public init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
        self = Color(red: Double(red)/255.0,
                     green: Double(green)/255.0,
                     blue: Double(blue)/255.0)
    }
}
```